# What should I write in commitinfo file for hooking my script if I want to commit an appropriate file?

Tags: cvs

Could you tell me can I add the line in commitinfo file if I want that the hook will be run if I commit an appropriate file?

Example: I have *.txt file
I added next line:
*.txt $CVSROOT/CVSROOT/hook.sh %p %s
and it is not working.

What should I do ?
Thanks.

Comment: I tried to use this:In addition to the common format strings (see syntax), commitinfo supports:

{s}
a list of the names of files to be committed

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you can put only folder in commitinfo.
ANd when you try to commit your script will be run and if all is ok
the commit will be executed.